# delete of @ in emailaddress when starting unsubscribe link in url

Tags: email

I work with WordPress 4.3.1 running Avada Child theme. For unsubscribe action I have wrote a simple script that starts this url:

```
<A HREF="http://test.domain.nl/unsubscribe?email=test@domain.nl">unsub</a>
```

When activate this url  the url is correct placed on the site, but the url is rewrote into:

```
<A HREF="http://test.domain.nl/unsubscribe?email=testdomain.nl">unsub</a>
```

So without the @ sign.

I have deactivated all plugins but the @ is still deleted.
It happens in all kind of browsers. 
Also when copying the link to the browser, the @ is deleted.

**strong text**!But when I put the @ manually into the url and start it again, the @ sign stays and the unsubscribe takes action.**strong text**

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) ) {    

$email = $_GET['email'];

$activeEmail    = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_row("SELECT email FROM wp_mm_external_emails WHERE active = 1 AND email = '".$email."' ");
$notactiveEmail     = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_row("SELECT email FROM wp_mm_external_emails WHERE active = 0 AND email = '".$email."' ");
$noEmail            = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_row("SELECT email FROM wp_mm_external_emails WHERE email = '".$email."'");

if($Active == 2) {
    $GLOBALS['wpdb']->update('wp_mm_external_emails',
                             array(
                                'active' => '0',
                                'date_unsubscribe' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time() ) 
                                ),
                                array('email' => $email)
                                );
}
}
```

input = test@domain.nl, url paste = test@domain.nl, rewrite url result = testdomain.nl. Rewrite is not caused by htaccess I have deactivate all rewrites there.

Does someone of you have an idea where I have to search to find a solution for this?

Comment: Post your PHP please. The generated HTML isn't very useful beyond just pointing a finger at the problem.

Comment: That is the code to process the submission not to create the link. Are you encoding the email address? `@` is a reserved character. That could be tripping this up but I haven't tested.

Comment: I do nothing with the emai address. That is why it is correct presented the first time in the url. But then the url is by a script rewriten and delete the @.

Comment: You are telling me that people hand write that url into the address bar? Is `unsubscribe` a valid page/url for your site?

Comment: the link is in the email: 
<A HREF="http://test.mijnmemorandum.nl/uitschrijven?email=[email]">testmm</a>. The email is designed with an Windows email prog that import the email addresses from the table into that prog. I work with this Supermailer program since 2008. Only in my newest site I get this problem. All other sites works fine. [email] var is correct filled. That is why is wrote this from the start.

Comment: I don't see any redirect when I try your URL. Something about the theme or a plugin is causing this but I don't know how to guess at what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always encode the url when outputting to a link tag:

`urlencode('http://test.domain.nl/unsubscribe?email=test@domain.nl')`

**Rewrite**

After further examination of your website. It's clear that the URL is being rewritten when a trailing slash is absent `uitschrijven?email=`.

Doing research I have stumbled on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8049382/1456997) which is identical to yours.

The solution is to add a `RewriteRule` rule in your `.htaccess` file.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: Hmm.. the complete url is in the customers mail. So there is no php possible. That is why I need the $_GET['email']. Or do I forget something?

Comment: I only test the $_GET['email'] if it is in the table and then start an action. But that is all after the rewrite of the url.

Comment: Look at the output code, the originating code!

Comment: this is the original output code: http://test.domain.nl/unsubscribe/?email=testnorus.nl

Comment: Find out where that is coming from!

Comment: see text above.. please

Comment: See my Rewrite solution

Comment: I have test the Rewrite suggestion, but without success. The trailing slash is constant present. My fault was a wrong url in the text above. My apologize for that.

Comment: Post your entire .htaccess for examination